# How to create widget for mobile app Xamarin Forms (for each OS separately)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, android-widget

We need to make a widget for a mobile application using xamarin forms for Android and iOS (for each OS separately). How to add the ability to add on a desktop widget to an existing application? How to add and edit a widget in a project?

Tried to find information but couldn't find it for xamarin forms